# Passing a function as parameter in javascript, undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function which is part of an object called `server`, i.e server.log is a function which I use to log data. There are other properties of server which I do not want to pass to other functions, though I want server.log to be available to functions in other files.

```
function test() {
    testingThis(server.log);
}

function testingThis(logf) {
    logf("test123");
}
```

I get an error saying

> Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

I am using happy console module to log (server.log works fine in test function).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably `server.log` expects `this` to refer to `server`. However, the way you call the function, `this` refers to the global object or `undefined` (in strict mode).

[Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function to `server`:

```
testingThis(server.log.bind(server));
```

See also [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196).

Comment: Yes you are right. Its working now :) Was this pointing to the object of testingThis function ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you came across this answer.  The question was confusing, ill-defined, and poorly explained.  I wouldn't have assumed the value/scope of `this` to be an issue here, because I did not see `this` being used at all.  The one helpful piece was the emit error message.

Comment: @user1692342: No. As I said, inside `logf` (`server.log`) `this` would refer to the global object or `undefined`.

Comment: @vol7ron: Just an educated guess from the error message + seeing that `log` looses its reference to `server` ... and my crystal ball of course!